# convert varchar to datetime dd/mm/yy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is the below format in the table with varchar as datatype need a query to convert it into datetime, cannot change the data types as there are dependencies , please provide a working query

```
10/19/2020 00:00:00.000000
08/17/2011 00:00:00.000000
02/18/2018 00:00:00.000000
02/27/2015 00:00:00.000000
11/22/2020 00:00:00.000000
11/14/2017 00:00:00.000000
```

the correct query should result in below format.

```
2008-07-15 00:00:00.000
2015-12-23 00:00:00.000
2008-07-15 00:00:00.000
2016-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Just a tip, don't confuse us - have matching sample data and expected result.

Comment: "Please provide a working query"?  Maybe you do some effort first?

Comment: Your sample data is `MM/dd/yyyy`, not `dd/MM/yyyy` as your title says. There are certainly not 14 or 27 months in a year. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I do not think we are supposed to do your whole work because you insist on not reading up on the documentation at all and just ask us to "pease provide working query, me not even trying".

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have a time component, so just convert to a date:

```
select convert(date, left(col, 10), 101)
```

If there is really a time component, you can use:

```
select convert(datetime , left(col, 10), 101) + convert(datetime, convert(time, right(col, 15)))
```

Comment: excellent thanks Gordon its working.. Thanks for the quick response.